# Java String remove double comma

Tags: java

How to remove double comma from given below string

```
String ashok = "RCEX1P.RXCLAIMNBR, RCEX1P.CLMSEQNBR , RCEX1P.CLAIMSTS,  ,RCOCDP.APR7N2APUIP1";
```

expected output should as follows

expected

```
ashok="RCEX1P.RXCLAIMNBR, RCEX1P.CLMSEQNBR , RCEX1P.CLAIMSTS,RCOCDP.APR7N2APUIP1";
```

Comment: What created the bad string? Why not fix it there rather than later?

Answer (score 1):

`replaceAll` with pattern `",\\s*,"` should do the job

```
ashok = ashok.replaceAll(",\\s*,",",")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know there's always gonna be two spaces between the commas just use replace:

```
ashok = ashok.replace(",  ,",",");
```

Comment: Note that this isn't valid Java - `'` is used for character literals; `"` is used for string literals.